# Execution Strategies

Tags: high-frequency, order-execution

I have a rather broad question. Not sure how to best put it.
Does anyone have any papers/resources on how to improve the execution model of any strategy?
Would it be different if strategy under question is a market making strategy vs a market taking strategy?

EDIT: What are some of the ways one can improve execution model of a market making strategy? I understand a lot of the research is prop, but is it possible to share some pointer?

Comment: I don't have any specific papers that come to mind, but I know that there has been quite a bit of research into viewing optimal trade execution as a stochastic control problem.

Comment: I'd say it's nearly impossible to decouple execution technique from a MM strategy - maybe consider reformulating the question?

Answer (score 2):

> What are some of the ways one can improve execution model of a market making strategy?

If your market making strategy is delta-neutral two-sided passive quoting, then your execution quality is really down to how quickly you update your prices when the market moves. Ideally you update your prices before the market moves (ie you have alpha) but if not, then you must optimise latency to react very quickly.